# Determine if a type is Nullable and get the base type?

Tags: templates, d

Let's say I have this function template:

```
void bar(T)(T obj) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to change the behavior of the function if `T` is some `Nullable!U`, so that if `obj.isNull` is `true`, I do some alternate flow, or otherwise continue as if a plain `U` type had been passed instead.

```
void bar(T)(T obj) {
    static if(is(T == Nullable!U)) { // ?
        if(obj.isNull) {
            writeln("Object was null!");
            return;
        }

        auto realObj = obj.get;
    } else {
        alias realObj = obj;
    }

    writeln("Object was "~to!string(realObj));
}
```

Is there a way to check if `T` is an instance of `Nullable`, and if so, get the wrapped type?

Or more generally, is there a way to check if type `T` is an instantiation of some template `Foo`, and get the template parameters if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide a specific overload for `Nullable`s:

```
void bar(T : Nullable!U, U)(T obj) {
    if (obj.isNull) {
        writeln("Object was null!");
        return;
    }

    bar(obj.get);
}

void bar(T)(T obj) {
    writeln("Object was "~to!string(obj));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the two-parameter version of nullable (ex. `Nullable!(uint, 0)`)? `(T : Nullable!(U,V), U, V : U)` doesn't seem to work; neither does `(T : Nullable!(U,V), U, V)`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: I think that might be the best that can be done without specifying everything explicitly – you’d need `U nullValue`, but `Nullable!(U, nullValue)` means that `U` has to be matched before `nullValue`, and they depend on each other, and it seems D can’t resolve that…

Answer (score 4):

Your code is mostly correct, all you need is to change this line:

`static if(is(T == Nullable!U))`

to this

`static if(is(T == Nullable!U, U))`, and `U` will be aliased to the type of the `Nullable` (i.e. `int`, ...)

Code: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/cc225c8d4ca3